# Is there a way to change redirect behavior for website hosting?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The google cloud storage documentation for [website configuration](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration) indicates that when a user requests a page without a slash, a slash is inserted for the user.

The resultant behavior in practice is that it redirects to the MainPageSuffix page directly, instead of just adding a slash.

So for example if you have a bucket with the MainPageSuffix set to 'index.html', and have the file /folder/index.html being served. Visiting /folder/ will serve the file directly, but visiting /folder will 301 redirect you to /folder/index.html instead of /folder/.

Is it possible to configure or somehow force /folder to redirect you to /folder/ instead of directly to the file?

Comment: I just posted the same question and then stumbled upon your post. Did you ever find a solution to this issue?